# How to inherit from ssl.SSLSocket correctly?

Tags: python, super

I found [this cod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554106/python-3-how-to-log-ssl-handshake-errors-from-server-side)e, and seems to do what I want, but apparently, Python 3 wants to a have a public constructor:

> TypeError: LoggingSSLSocket does not have a public constructor. Instances are returned by SSLContext.wrap_socket().

I tried

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

but that doesn't seem to work:

> TypeError: descriptor '**init**' requires a 'super' object but received a 'LoggingSSLSocket'

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's `super().__init__(...`, with parentheses.

Comment: @jasonharper that didn't work. It still complains about a missing public constructor